# The finest integers are palindromes

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge, palindrome

**Challenge**:

> Reverse the digits of a number and add it to the original
>   until the number is a palindrome

**Specifications**:

> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
>   Each line in this file is one test case containing an integer n < 10,000.
>
> Assume each test case will always have an answer and
>   that it is computable with less than 100 iterations.
>
> For each line of input, print a line of output
>   containing the number of iterations to compute the palindrome 
>   and the resulting palindrome, on one line separated by a single space.

**Solution**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseAndAdd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            findAndPrintPalindrome(input.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private static void findAndPrintPalindrome(String line){
        System.out.println(getPalindrome(line));
    }

    private static String getPalindrome(String line) {
        int reverseCount = 0,
            currentNum = Integer.parseInt(line)
        ;

        while (!isPalindromic(currentNum)) {
            currentNum += reverse(currentNum);
            reverseCount++;
        }

        return reverseCount + " " + currentNum;
    }

    private static boolean isPalindromic(int s) {
        return s == reverse(s);
    }

    private static int reverse(int n) {
        return Integer.parseInt(
            new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(n)).reverse().toString()
        );
    }
}
```

**Sample Input**:

> 8
>   125
>   195

**Sample Output**:

> 0 8
>   1 646
>   4 9339

I'm looking to pinpoint:

1. Anything I could alter to optimize this program.
2. General feedback on good vs poor practices in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `reverse` gets called twice in every step

In every step of the process to finding a palindromic number,
the `reverse` method gets called twice:

> ```
>     while (!isPalindromic(currentNum)) {
>         currentNum += reverse(currentNum);
>         reverseCount++;
>     }
>
> private static boolean isPalindromic(int s) {
>     return s == reverse(s);
> }
> ```

First it gets called in the `while` loop's condition statement,
then again inside the loop body.
This is a waste,
it would be better to refactor to only call once per iteration.

Instead of `reverseCount`,
the name `stepCount` would seem slightly more appropriate,
but this may be just a matter of taste.

#### `isPalindromic` is simple but lazy

Although the implementation of `isPalindromic` is sweet and simple,
it's wasteful and inaccurate.

It involves converting the number to String, reversing, and then converting back to integer.
A more efficient way would be to compare the digits of position \$i\$ and \$n - i - 1\$, until you reach position \$n/2\$.

The method will not work with negative numbers because `reverse` will not work with negative numbers.

Here's an implementation using math, that works with negative numbers too:

```
private static boolean isPalindromic(int num) {
    int digits = (int) Math.log10(Math.abs(num)) + 1;
    int firstDivisor = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1);
    int lastDivisor = 1;
    while (firstDivisor > lastDivisor) {
        int firstDigit = num / firstDivisor % 10;
        int lastDigit = num / lastDivisor % 10;
        if (firstDigit != lastDigit) {
            return false;
        }
        firstDivisor /= 10;
        lastDivisor *= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And some unit tests to go with it:

```
@Test
public void testPalindromic_3() {
    assertTrue(isPalindromic(3));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_13() {
    assertFalse(isPalindromic(13));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_22() {
    assertTrue(isPalindromic(22));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_333() {
    assertTrue(isPalindromic(333));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_1991() {
    assertTrue(isPalindromic(1991));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_334() {
    assertFalse(isPalindromic(334));
}

@Test
public void testPalindromic_minus12321() {
    assertTrue(isPalindromic(-12321));
}
```

#### `reverse` is simple but lazy

As mentioned above,
the simple but lazy implementation breaks on negative numbers.
It also breaks on numbers that cause integer overflow when reversed.
And like with `isPalindromic`,
the logic is wasteful.
It would be better to implement this too using basic math logic:

```
private static int reverse(int num) {
    long reversed = 0;
    int work = num;
    while (work != 0) {
        reversed *= 10;
        reversed += work % 10;
        if (reversed > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reversing this number will cause integer overflow: " + num);
        }
        work /= 10;
    }
    return (int) reversed;
}
```

Notice the check for integer overflow in the middle.
It's a mistake of the caller to try to reverse an `int` that would turn out to be too big.

As with any non-trivial implementation, it's important to have unit tests:

```
@Test
public void testReverse_3() {
    assertEquals(3, reverse(3));
}

@Test
public void testReverse_34() {
    assertEquals(43, reverse(34));
}

@Test
public void testReverse_41() {
    assertEquals(14, reverse(41));
}

@Test
public void testReverse_123() {
    assertEquals(321, reverse(123));
}

@Test
public void testReverse_100() {
    assertEquals(1, reverse(100));
}

@Test
public void testReverse_123456789() {
    assertEquals(987654321, reverse(123456789));
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testReverse_1234567899() {
    reverse(1234567899);
}
```

#### `getPalindrome`

As others already pointed out,
`getPalindrome` is not a great name for this method.

It's also not great that it takes a String and converts it to integer,
because it's an additional responsibility,
so it violates the *Single Responsibility Principle*.

This way of declaring variables looks odd:

> ```
>     int reverseCount = 0,
>         currentNum = Integer.parseInt(line)
>     ;
> ```

I'd recommend to just stick to traditional style:

```
    int reverseCount = 0;
    int currentNum = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

As with anything non-trivial,
it's extremely helpful to have unit tests.
I also included test cases suggested by @thepace.
I renamed the method to `stepsToPalindromic` and made it take an integer parameter instead of String.

```
@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_8() {
    assertEquals("0 8", stepsToPalindromic(8));
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_125() {
    assertEquals("1 646", stepsToPalindromic(125));
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_195() {
    assertEquals("4 9339", stepsToPalindromic(195));
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_0() {
    assertEquals("0 0", stepsToPalindromic(0));
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testStepsToPalindromic_max() {
    stepsToPalindromic(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_minus1() {
    assertEquals("0 -1", stepsToPalindromic(-1));
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_minus195() {
    assertEquals("4 -9339", stepsToPalindromic(-195));
}

@Test
public void testStepsToPalindromic_9998() {
    assertEquals("6 8836388", stepsToPalindromic(9998));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- Indentation and formatting
      currentNum = Integer.parseInt(line)
      ;
- Is there a chance of an MAX_INT overflow for `reverse()`. Seems unlikely for the given contraints though.
- Since n is an integer, so negatives are allowed. In that case `.reverse()` will cause problem. Please check the constraints.
- `getPalindrome()` should return a palindrome instead of an output you wish to have. Instead either have the function name changed. (Though not a big concern but ensure that when I see a function name, it shoul dbe intuitive so that I do not have to check the code for the actual output.)
- Test cases:

  1. Include 0, 9998 (max non palindromic `n`).
  2. Negatives (if constraints dont mention so).
  3. Invalid input. (Not handled by your program and may not be required but would help for a production code and not a programming challenge).

Optimisation:

- `reverse()` though takes negligible time (in nanoseconds) but can be improved to handle all above cases along with speed in calculation. Ideone [link](http://ideone.com/VqxZZF)

  ```
  private static int reverseInt(int n) {
      int rev = 0;
      while(n>0){
          rev = (rev*10)+n%10;
          n=n/10;
     }
     return rev;
  }
  ```